# Why margin-top is not working when I'm trying to fadeIn. It works fine when I simple use display block

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a span for error message, assigned a class .error_msg it has the margin-top of 5px. When I change its display property to block it works fine but when I try to fadeIn it ignores the margin-top.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id=first_name>
First Name<br />
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr><td><img src='images/form_error.png' class="error_image" id="form_first_name_err_img" <?php echo ($error_first_name == true) ? "style='display: block'" : "style='display: none'" ; ?> /></td><td><input align="middle" id="form_first_name" class="form_field1" type="text" name="first_name" /></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><span class="error_msg" id="form_first_name_err_msg" <?php echo ($error_first_name == true) ? "style='display: block'" : "style='display: none'" ; ?>>This cannot be left blank.</span></td></tr>
</table>
</div><!-- eof first_name -->
<div id=last_name>
Last Name<br />
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr><td><img src='images/form_error.png' class="error_image" id="form_last_name_err_img" <?php echo ($error_last_name == true) ? "style='display: block'" : "style='display: none'" ; ?> /></td><td><input align="middle" id="form_last_name" class="form_field1" type="text" name="last_name" /></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><span class="error_msg" id="form_last_name_err_msg" <?php echo ($error_last_name == true) ? "style='display: block'" : "style='display: none'" ; ?>>Last name should be of minimum 2 characters.</span></td></tr>
</table>
</div><!-- eof last_name -->
```

CSS:

```
.error_msg {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
    function check_first_name() {

        var first_name_length = $("#form_first_name").val().length;

        if(first_name_length < 1) {
            $("#form_first_name_err_img").fadeIn();
            $("#form_first_name_err_msg").fadeIn();
            error_first_name = true;
        } else {
            $("#form_first_name_err_img").hide();
            $("#form_first_name_err_msg").hide();
        }

    }

function check_last_name() {

    var last_name_length = $("#form_last_name").val().length;

    if(last_name_length < 2) {
        $("#form_last_name_err_img").css( "display", "block" );
        $("#form_last_name_err_msg").css( "display", "block" );
        error_last_name = true;
    } else {
        $("#form_last_name_err_img").css( "display", "none" );
        $("#form_last_name_err_msg").css( "display", "none" );
    }   

}
```

Comment: Please provide fiddle, that will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

`<span>`s and `<img>`s are not block level elements. After the `fadeIn()`, if you check their display properties, they'll be `inline`. When you specifically set them to `block` they'll honour the margins, but not when auto-set to `inline` during a `fadeIn()`

Instead of `fadeIn()`, you can try:

```
$("#form_first_name_err_img")
    .css({opacity: 0, display: 'block'})
    .animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast');
```

Comment: I had the same issue almost and This fixed it for me Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display: none;` use `visibility: hidden;` in your css. which allows space allocation for it on the page

Answer (score 0):

```
.error_msg {
     color: red;
     font-size: 12px;
     margin-top: 5px;
     display:block;
     opacity:0;
     filter:alpha(opacity=0); /*** this is for old ie browsers *******/
}
```

here is basic demo link

http://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/Q44jP/1/